# how to make the symfony debug bar collapsed by default?

Tags: symfony1

is there a command to make the debug bar collapsed for every request?

I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box, but I've implemented the following small JavaScript hack (my example requires jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  if (typeof sfWebDebugToggleMenu != 'undefined') {
    sfWebDebugToggleMenu();
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 3.0.9, javascript:

```
window.localStorage['sf2/profiler/toolbar/displayState'] = 'none';
```